# C++ call public method of another child class

Tags: c++, oop

is there an elegant version to access a method of an another child class?
For a better understanding please watch my c++ code.

Its really important that external functions / classes can access furthermore the addchild() method!!

C++ Code:

```
class User {
    protected:
        int userid;
        std::string givenname;
        std::string surname;
        std::string birthday;
};

class Child: public User {
    public:
        int addchild() {
            //Doing the required stuff to add a new child
        }
};

class Parent: public User {
    public:
        int addparent() {
            //Here we have to add a new child among others
            addchild();
        }
};


int main() {
    Child child1;
    child1.addchild();

    Parent parent1;
    parent1.addparent();
}
```

UML:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'elegant'? According to your diagram, `Parent` should have no information about existence of `Child`.

Comment: Can't be done. You either need to give `Parent` its own definition of `addChild()` or let `Parent` derive from a base class that defines `addChild()`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen yeah I know! Thats my problem how can I make a relationship between them?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your problem. You want `Parent` class to have some object of `Child` class in it? Because you need object of `Child` class to call method `addChild()` on it.

Comment: In `Parent::addparent`, on which object do you expect `addchild()` to act? There's only a `Parent` and its base `User` subobject in this context, no `Child`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen thereabouts... The class Parent must access to a method from the class Child. And my question is HOW (with an object? or is there a more elegant version out there?)

Comment: @Quentin this is my question.. HOW can I do this to access the other method in the other class?

Comment: Here's an idea: change your desing. Parent and Child **are not** extended cases of User. Remove this whole inheritance stuff and instead add a class `ParentChildConnection` with two pointers to `User` inside. Then you get rid of this weird issue. If you need an efficient scan/lookup then add an indexing code (together with `UsersCollection` class) as well. Try to mimick a database. Otherwise you will end up with spaghetti code.

Comment: @XM37 well, you have to create a `Child` object somewhere to call its member function. But it's unclear to me how you'd end up wanting to call a member function without knowing which object it should be called on.

Comment: @XM37 Your question makes no sense. To access a non-static member of the Child class you **must** have a Child object. Where is that object? If you have that object then it's easy, just use the child object to call the child method.

Comment: It can be easily done, just supply a `Child` class instance to call the method on `int addparent(Child & child) { child.addchild(); }`

Comment: You have a method `addChild()` in class `Child`. You always need a `Child` object to call it. If it's not related to a particular object, make is `static`. The question how `Parent` should know handle `Child` object is different one. It could be a member of `Parent`, if `Parent` should be the only one ever to access it. `Parent` can have a pointer or reference member, if `Child` is created outside and passed to `Parent`. Finally, `Parent` can have no `Child` member, but instead take as `addParent` parameter. I'd suggest picking up a book on software design (in C++).

Answer (score 0):

You could use CRTP for your parent class: https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/05/12/curiously-recurring-template-pattern/ (more general: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Because it got no attention I changed the original code sample so that it is using CRTP:

```
#include <string>

class User {
    protected:
        int userid;
        std::string givenname;
        std::string surname;
        std::string birthday;
};

class Child: public User {
    public:
        int addchild() {
            //Doing the required stuff to add a new child
        }
};

template <typename BASE>
class Parent: public BASE {
    public:
        int addparent() {
            //Here we have to add a new child among others
            this->addchild();
        }
};


int main() {
    Child child1;
    child1.addchild();

    Parent<Child> parent1;
    parent1.addparent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done in the current design. You either need to have an object of `Child` inside `Parent` class or pass an object of `Child` as a argument to `addparent()` function.

```
class Parent: public User {
    private:
        Child child; //Have an instance of Child class here to be able 
                     //to use addchild() in this class 
    public:            
        int addparent() {
           //Here we have to add a new child among others
           child.addchild();
        }
};
```

Or passing a argument like this:

```
class Parent: public User {
    private:
        Child child; //Have an instance of Child class here to be able 
                     //to use addchild() in this class 
    public:            
        int addparent(Child & child) {
             child.addchild(); 
    }
};
```

I am not sure about how you are structuring your entire class and what you intend to do with them.

Explore design patterns at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/design_pattern_overview.htm

Also, look up the concept of composition in C++ at http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/102-composition/

This might help you come up with a better design.